# How to construct a matrix of T with respect to some basis?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, field-theory, linear-transformations

Say we have $F:=\Bbb F_3(\alpha)$ where α is a root of $f(x)=x^3-x-1$ then $ F:=\{a+b\alpha +c\alpha^2|a,b,c \in \Bbb F_3\}$ So a basis for F as a vector space over $\Bbb F_3$ is $\beta:=\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2\}$.

Now say we have a map $T:F \rightarrow F$ s.t. $T(x)=\alpha x $ $\forall x \in F$

Then would I be correct in saying that the matrix M of T with respect to the basis β would be found in the following way ?

say $\beta:=\{1 , \alpha, \alpha^2\}=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$

$T(1)=\alpha=0v_1+1v_2+0,v_3$

$T(\alpha)=\alpha^2=0v_1+0v_2+1v_3$

$T(\alpha^2)=\alpha^3=\alpha+1=1v_1+1v_2+0v_3$

So

$T(v_1)=\begin {pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$T(v_2)=\begin {pmatrix} 0\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$T(v_3)=\begin {pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

So $M=[T(v_1)_B,T(v_2)_B,T(v_3)_B]= \begin {pmatrix} 0 & 0 &1\\ 1 &0 &1 \\ 0 &1&0 \end{pmatrix} $

I found this method on https://yutsumura.com/matrix-of-linear-transformation-with-respect-to-a-basis-consisting-of-eigenvectors/. Is it correct ?

Comment: The method looks right but M is wrong (but presumably you can fix it).

Comment: I edited the typos, it is now correct.

Comment: Can’t imagine the maths department will be too happy to hear about a student plagiarising assignment answers.

Comment: @user186914 If there is an ethical problem related to this question you should bring it up at your department. I'm not seeing anything serious here.  The question isn't that great - the answer to *Is it correct?* has no value to anyone but the asker. The method may be a bit more interesting. Anyway, I struggle to see how you plagiarize an assignment?